# Regex to capture consecutive words

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a list of mobile device names like

```
"Sony Xperia Z1 Compact"
"Samsung Galaxy Trend Plus"
"Samsung Galaxy Tab 2"
```

I need a regex to create tags from those strings to match consecutive words in this way (expected result):

```
["Sony", "Sony Xperia", "Sony Xperia Z1", "Sony Xperia Z1 Compact"]
```

I have tried something with a positive lookahead:

```
/(?=([a-z]+\s+[a-z]+))[a-z]+/i
```

I obtained:

```
model = "Samsung Galaxy Trend Plus"
"Samsung Galaxy Trend Plus"
model.match(/(?=([a-z]+\s+[a-z]+))[a-z]+/i)
["Samsung", "Samsung Galaxy"]
```

But this does not work when you have one word, so, after adding an optional group:

```
/(?=([a-z]+\s+[a-z]+))|[a-z]+/i
```

I obtained:

```
model = "Samsung"
"Samsung"
model.match(/(?=([a-z]+\s+[a-z]+))|[a-z]+/i)
["Samsung", undefined]
```

So, trying to generalize:

```
/(?=([a-z]+\s+[a-z]+))(?=([a-z]+\s+[a-z]+\s+[a-z]+))(?=([a-z]+\s+[a-z]+\s+[a-z]+\s+[a-z]+))[a-z]+/i
```

I get

```
"Samsung Galaxy Trend Plus"
model.match(/(?=([a-z]+\s+[a-z]+))(?=([a-z]+\s+[a-z]+\s+[a-z]+))(?=([a-z]+\s+[a-z]+\s+[a-z]+\s+[a-z]+))[a-z]+/i)

["Samsung", "Samsung Galaxy", "Samsung Galaxy Trend", "Samsung Galaxy Trend Plus"]
```

And supposed to have up to *N* words, how to make this regex generic (a degree of freedom on the *N* words variable)?
Also, how to get rid of the `undefined` ? As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21026134/why-javascript-string-match-includes-undefined) I should use a non-capturing group, thus this would prevent me to capture consecutive words in the way I was doing.

Comment: Does the solution have to be a reg exp?

Comment: Yes, it 'must' be a regex.

Comment: I do not think `Sony Xperia Compact` is formed from consecutive words. [How about this solution](http://jsfiddle.net/e6w0mp31/)?

Comment: @stribizhev right I have fixed the 'expected result'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can suggest almost pure regex solution. Almost because I need to swap word order in order to get correct output subphrases:

```js
var re = /(?=\b((?:\S+[ \t]*)+))/g; 
var str = 'Sony Xperia Z1 Compact';
 
str = str.split(' ').reverse().join(' ');
while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
        re.lastIndex++;
    }
    document.getElementById("t").innerHTML += m[1].split(' ').reverse().join(' ') + "<br/>";
}
```

```html
<div id="t"/>
```

The `(?=\b((?:\S+[ \t]*)+))` regex is capturing all chunks of non-whitespace characters followed by optional whitespace (but not a newline symbol) and we make sure we get only whole words using a `\b` word boundary.

I think it is difficult to get it without reversing since we do not have a variable width lookbehind in JS.

Comment: That makes sense. That's the best solution so far through pure regex!

Answer (score 3):

For those who have a similar problem, but don't want to (ab)use regexes:

```js
name = "Samsung Galaxy Trend Plus";

result = name.split(/\s+/g).map(function(_, i, a) {
  return a.slice(0, i + 1).join(" ")
});

document.write(result);
```

Comment: Good solution with no regex and making use of function mapping.

Comment: Much more succinct than my effort, and introduced me to the array map function

Answer (score 0):

Although this won't help the OP as they stated in comments that it 'must' be a regex solution, a quick way to achieve this with javascript would be to split the string on space chars then rebuild another array in a loop:

```
var s = 'Sony Xperia Z1 Compact';

var a = s.split(' ');
var b = [], c = [];

for(var i=0; i < a.length; i++) {
    b.push(a[i]);
    c.push(b.join(' '));    
}
```

`c.toString();` = 
`Sony,Sony Xperia,Sony Xperia Z1,Sony Xperia Z1 Compact`

see [demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/garyh/a1yqLs1e/2/)

Comment: It's a good solution without regex, unfortunately I need a regex. Thank you anyways.